# display last column as new row

Tags: html, css

I have a table with sortable functionality. There is a description column in the table that makes row height very large.

I want to display the last column(description column) as new row but not actually new row. If i make it actually new row it would disturb my sortable functionality.

I have been searching for some hours but in vain. How could i do it?

**In other words:**
i want to change this....
[image: i want to change this]

to this.... but should be 1 row
[image: to this]

Here is the related code:

```
<tr class=" edit_li fee" id="lineitem" value="fee">
<td class="align_left normal">
    <span>2014-01-27</span>
</td>
<td class="align_center tk_name_hover normal" oldtitle="Penatibus primis." title="" data-hasqtip="true">
    <span class="tk_name ">
    TEST
    </span>
</td>
<td class="align_left no_wrap normal">
    <span>
    Vehicula ultricies sagittis diam metus aptent primis maecenas donec. Feugiat tempus lectus mi felis aenean dictum sodales per suspendisse etiam sem egestas. Risus semper. - 
    </span>
    <span class="tk_name "></span>
</td>
<td class="align_right normal">
    <span title="" class="tk_rate " data-hasqtip="true">
        475.00 
        <div class="unit-small">USD </div>
    </span>
</td>
<td class="align_right normal">2.00</td>
<td class="text-right last">
    <span title="" discount="0" li_tax="0" class="align_right line_item_total" style="display: block" data-hasqtip="true">
        950.00 
        <div class="unit-small">USD </div>
    </span>
</td>
```

Comment: Would the `tfoot` element not do the job?

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: I have updated. see the edit.

Comment: @lonesomeday there would be description for every row. not for the whole table so tfoot will not work

Comment: So you want the description box beneath the table but still as the 3th row?

Comment: did you tried like this http://jsfiddle.net/Lnq4uorq/2/?

Comment: @Blank each row of table would have a row description but it would be displayed as successive row/very next row.

Comment: @K.B.M that would be footer. what i want is each row displaying its description as  table's next row not the footer. there may be several line items in the table

Comment: Can you create a demo to help you better

Comment: i have pasted the relevant code code.  More n more code will make question bulky and difficult to understand.

Comment: Just to know... How is your table generated ? Pure HTML/CSS like your tags say ? PHP or ASP(.NET) ? Something else ?

Comment: its ruby on rails. table row are generated by a ruby loop

Comment: You should edit your tags and add it. It might be more relevant with the concerned loop as it will be possible to understand the process :)

Comment: I would add it as a regular row, assign a `data` attribute to the rows that should be sortable, and then take that attribute into account when sorting the table. Remember to link the rows together and move them both during sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
<td class="first_td">
<div class="table_row">
  <div class="table_cell">
    <div class="conta_desc">
      <span>
        <b>Description:</b> <%= "#{item.item_description} - " unless item.item_description.blank? %>
      </span>
      <%= "(#{item.task_code})" unless item.task_code.blank? %> <%= "(#{item.activity_code})" unless item.activity_code.blank? %>
      <span class="tk_name <%= validation_class %>"><%= @invoice.validation_errors(item.id) unless @invoice.blank? %></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</td>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
  .table_row{
    display: table-row;
  }
  .table_cell{
    display: table-cell;
    max-width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .conta_desc{
    width: 775px;
    white-space: initial;
  }
```

the output is:
[image]

Comment: The implication in your question was that you could not change the structure of your HTML as your sorting function was dependent on it remaining as-is.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this in CSS alone, without touching the HTML. Using flexbox, you can change the `order` of each cell so that the required cell appears last. Then, by allowing the flexed items to wrap, you could also get the required cell to drop onto a new line.

[More information on flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)

**EXAMPLE**

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;font-family:arial;font-size:14px;}
table{
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-spacing:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:50%;
}
tr{
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:row wrap;
    width:100%;
}
td{
    flex:1 1 25%;
    order:1;
    padding:5px;
}
td:nth-child(3){
    background:#ccc;
    flex:4 1 100%;
    font-weight:bold;
    order:4;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>R1D1</td>
        <td>R1D2</td>
        <td>R1D3</td>
        <td>R1D4</td>
        <td>R1D5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>R2D1</td>
        <td>R2D2</td>
        <td>R2D3</td>
        <td>R2D4</td>
        <td>R2D5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>R3D1</td>
        <td>R3D2</td>
        <td>R3D3</td>
        <td>R3D4</td>
        <td>R3D5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please note that Using CSS display properties (flex, grid, block etc.) on a <table> overrides its native semantics and renders it as non-table for screen readers. Avoid