# Responsive tables - Wrapping or alternatives

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm quite sure by now that tables are not designed to wrap.

There is a specific thing I'm trying to achieve with a table when browsing with small view-ports: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9cuy.png

What I want is a wrapping table which is wide when viewing on a larger monitor, but wraps when viewed on smaller screens, like the examples in the image (ignore the poor editing please.)

What I have now is a table which does not wrap, but scrolls horizontally.
Are there any viable alternatives to achieve the desired effect?

```css
.floor-plans table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}

.floor-plans table tr:first-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.floor-plans table td,
table th {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}

.floor-plans table td {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="floor-plans mb-50 table-responsive">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Rooms</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Bathrooms</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Size</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Price</strong></td>
        <td><strong>MLS&reg;#</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Type</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Maintenance Fee</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>743 sq ft</td>
        <td>$628,000</td>
        <td>r845621</td>
        <td>Highrise</td>
        <td>$299</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: No need to excuse yourself. Please be very explicit and detailed about your question so that masters of the subject matter might understand it. Commentary about you've tried is not needed. Specific and detailed descriptions of what you are trying to achieve and specific and detailed questions are much more likely to get answers.

Comment: I'm sorry but, I don't find your suggestions helpful. Is my link not enough to understand what I want to achieve? I don't understand how you don't understand, and I don't understand how I can be more detailed than a legitimate picture of what I want. I'll edit it, but it'll only become more convoluted. In fact, why don't I remove everything and just leave the photo? - Done

Comment: I'm not a topic expert, I'm just trying to help you get your question answered. Being explicit about what behavior you want on mobile is better than a photo. Do you want the table columns to be clipped on the right side? Do you have any other way of displaying this on mobile? Please, I'm just making suggestions for to get your question answered. Are there alternatives for displaying your data on a small screen? Formal language goes a long way.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29798197/display-last-column-as-new-row, may be this would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Nik I'll play around with it. I tried many things so far but not this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Datatable will never responsive easily**

You can use bootstrap datatable if you want to responsive, I hope this will work for you.

[Bootstrap Resonsive datatable](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/integration/responsive-bootstrap.html)

Comment: Not sure how I missed this, but this is beautiful and will help me immensely with future tables as well. Thank you!